# Access permissions in Active Directory not working

Tags: active-directory, permissions

I've a server running Active Directory, and two servers for storage in my domain. Currently all the folders are open, but I wanna set up access authorizations with Active Directory groups, so only the allowed groups are able to access specific folders.

I'm adding shared folders to Windows Settings > Security Settings > File System (see image for reference). Then I configure the groups that can access it and their permissions.

But for some reason, the policy doesnt get applied (I've tried gpupdate), and the users without access permission, still can see and access the folder and it's content.

What am I doing wrong?

[image: ref image]

Comment: You may be making this way more difficult then it probably needs to be. Why not create and populate security groups and use those to secure your folders?

Comment: @joeqwerty I'm aware that I can change the permissions of specific folders by opening up the properties from context menu (not sure if you mean that), but this seems to provide a centralized way of managing it. I'd be happy with some way that works, but currently I wasnt very lucky when looking for information on the net.